# How buffered input works

Tags: assembly, input, dos, x86-16

The input in next program (using DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah) works OK, but when I ask to show the output, DOS doesn't display anything at all. How is this possible?

```
        ORG     256
        mov     dx, msg1
        mov     ah, 09h                 ;DOS.WriteString
        int     21h
        mov     dx, buf
        mov     ah, 0Ah                 ;DOS.BufferedInput
        int     21h
        mov     dx, msg2
        mov     ah, 09h                 ;DOS.WriteString
        int     21h
        mov     dx, buf
        mov     ah, 09h                 ;DOS.WriteString
        int     21h
        mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
msg1:   db      'Input : ', '$'
buf:    db      20 dup ('$')
msg2:   db      13, 10, 'Output : ', '$'
; --------------------------------------
```

**Notice** This self-answered Q/A comes with a two-part answer. Anyone interested should begin their reading with the *accepted* answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at how you defined your input buffer (`buf: db 20 dup ('$')`), I get it
that you want to cut corners and have the input already $-terminated ready for
re-displaying it. Sadly this messes up the required settings for the DOS input
function 0Ah and your program is in serious problems with a potential buffer
overrun.
Moreover using $-termination is not the brightest choice that you can make
since the $ character could already appear amongst the inputted characters.
All the example programs that I present below will use zero-termination
instead.

## Inputting text using `int 21h AH=0Ah`

This [Buffered STDIN Input](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) function gets characters from the keyboard and
continues doing so until the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. All
characters and the final carriage return are placed in the storage space that
starts at the 3rd byte of the input buffer supplied by the calling program
via the pointer in `DS:DX`.
The character count, not including the final carriage return, is stored in the
2nd byte of the input buffer.
It's the responsibility of the calling program to tell DOS how large the
storage space is. Therefore you must put its length in the 1st byte of the
input buffer before calling this function. To allow for an input of 1
character you set the storage size at 2. To allow for an input of 254
characters you set the storage size at 255.
If you don't want to be able to *recall from the template* any previous input,
then it is best to also zero the 2nd byte. Basically the template is the
pre-existing (and valid) content in the input buffer that the calling program
provided. If pre-existing content is invalid then the template is not
available.

Surprisingly this function has limited editing facilities.

- <kbd>Escape</kbd> Removes all characters from the current input.
  The current input is abandoned but stays on screen and the cursor is placed on
  the next row, beneath where the input first started.
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> Removes the last character from the current input.
  Works as expected if the input stays within a single row on screen.
  If on the other hand the input spans several rows then this backspacing will
  stop at the left edge of the screen. From then on there will be a serious
  discrepancy between the logical input and the visual input because *logically*
  backspacing will go on until the 1st position in the storage space is reached!
- <kbd>F6</kbd> Inserts an end-of-file character (1Ah) in the current input.
  The screen will show "^Z".
- <kbd>F7</kbd> Inserts a zero byte in the current input.
  The screen will show "^@".
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> Transitions to the next row (executing a
  carriage return and linefeed), nothing is added to the current input, and you
  can't go back.

Many more editing keys are available. They are all reminiscent of *EDLIN.EXE*,
the ancient DOS line editor, which is a text editor where each previous line
becomes the template on which you build the next line.

- <kbd>F1</kbd> Copies one character from the template to the new line.
- <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>...</kbd>  Copies all characters from the template to the new line, up to the character specified.
- <kbd>F3</kbd> Copies all remaining characters in the template to the new line.
- <kbd>F4</kbd> + <kbd>...</kbd> Skips over the characters in the template, up
  to the character specified.
- <kbd>F5</kbd> Makes the new line the new template.
- <kbd>Escape</kbd> Clears the current input and leaves the template unchanged.
- <kbd>Delete</kbd> Skips one character in the template.
- <kbd>Insert</kbd> Enters or exits insert mode.
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> Deletes the last character of the new line and places the cursor back one character in the template.
- <kbd>Left</kbd> Same as Backspace.
- <kbd>Right</kbd> Same as F1.

Tabs are expanded by this function. Tab expansion is the process of replacing
ASCII 9 by a series of one or more spaces (ASCII 32) until the cursor reaches
a column position that is a multiple of 8.
This tab expansion only happens on screen. The storage space will hold ASCII 9.

This function does <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>
checking.

When this function finishes, the cursor will be in the far left column on the
current row.

Example 1, Buffered STDIN input.

```
        ORG     256                     ;Create .COM program
        cld
        mov     si, msg1
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     dx, buf
        mov     ah, 0Ah                 ;DOS.BufferedInput
        int     21h
        mov     si, msg2
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     si, buf+2
        movzx   bx, byte [si-1]         ;Get character count
        mov     word [si+bx+1], 10      ;Keep CR, append LF and 0
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ds:si) OUT ()
WriteStringDOS:
        pusha
        jmps    .b
.a:     mov     dl, al
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
.b:     lodsb
        test    al, al
        jnz     .a
        popa
        ret
; --------------------------------------
buf:    db      255, 16, "I'm the template", 13, 255-16-1+2 dup (0)
msg1:   db      'Choose color ? ', 0
msg2:   db      10, 'You chose ', 0
; --------------------------------------
```

## Inputting text using `int 21h AH=3Fh`

When used with predefined handle 0 (in `BX`) this [Read From File Or Device](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2783.htm)
function gets characters from the keyboard and continues doing so until the
user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. All characters (never more than 127) and the
final carriage return plus an additional linefeed are placed in a private
buffer within the DOS kernel. This now becomes the new template.
Hereafter the function will write in the buffer provided at `DS:DX`, the amount
of bytes that were requested in the `CX` parameter. If `CX` specified a number
that is less than the number of bytes generated by this input, one or more
additional calls to this function are required to retrieve the complete input.
As long as there are characters remaining to be picked up, this function will
not launch another input session using the keyboard! This is even true between
different programs or sessions of the same program.

All the editing keys described in the previous section are available.

Tabs are expanded on screen only, not in the template.

This function does <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>
checking.

When this function finishes, the cursor will be in the far left column on the

- current row if the terminating linefeed was not among the returned bytes.
- next row if the terminating linefeed was among the returned bytes.

Example 2a, Read From File Or Device, pick up all at once.

```
        ORG     256                     ;Create .COM program
        cld
        mov     si, msg1
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     dx, buf
        mov     cx, 127+2               ;Max input is 127 chars + CR + LF
        xor     bx, bx                  ;STDIN=0
        mov     ah, 3Fh                 ;DOS.ReadFileOrDevice
        int     21h                     ; -> AX CF
        jc      Exit
        mov     bx, ax                  ;Bytes count is less than CX
        mov     si, msg2
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     si, buf
        mov     [si+bx], bh             ;Keep CR and LF, append 0 (BH=0)
        call    WriteStringDOS
Exit:   mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ds:si) OUT ()
WriteStringDOS:
        pusha
        jmps    .b
.a:     mov     dl, al
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
.b:     lodsb
        test    al, al
        jnz     .a
        popa
        ret
; --------------------------------------
buf:    db      127+2+1 dup (0)
msg1:   db      'Choose color ? ', 0
msg2:   db      'You chose ', 0
; --------------------------------------
```

Example 2b, Read From File Or Device, pick up one byte at a time.

```
        ORG     256                     ;Create .COM program
        cld
        mov     si, msg1
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     dx, buf
        mov     cx, 1
        xor     bx, bx                  ;STDIN=0
        mov     ah, 3Fh                 ;DOS.ReadFileOrDevice
        int     21h                     ; -> AX CF
        jc      Exit
        mov     si, msg2
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     si, dx                  ;DX=buf, CX=1, BX=0
Next:   mov     ah, 3Fh                 ;DOS.ReadFileOrDevice
        int     21h                     ; -> AX CF
        jc      Exit
        call    WriteStringDOS          ;Display a single byte
        cmp     byte [si], 10
        jne     Next
Exit:   mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ds:si) OUT ()
WriteStringDOS:
        pusha
        jmps    .b
.a:     mov     dl, al
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
.b:     lodsb
        test    al, al
        jnz     .a
        popa
        ret
; --------------------------------------
msg1:   db      'Choose color ? ', 0
msg2:   db      10, 'You chose '
buf:    db      0, 0
; --------------------------------------
```

## Inputting text using `int 2Fh AX=4810h`

This [DOSKEY Buffered STDIN Input](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/703-int_2fh_4810h__get_keyboard_input_with_doskey_editing.html) function can only be invoked [if the
DOSKEY.COM TSR was installed](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/702-int_2fh_4800h__is_doskey_com_installed_.html). It operates much like the regular Buffered
STDIN Input function 0Ah (see above), but has all the same editing
possibilities as the DOS command line, including the ability to use all of
the DOSKEY special keys.

- <kbd>Up</kbd> Gets previous item from history.
- <kbd>Down</kbd> Gets next item from history.
- <kbd>F7</kbd> Shows a list of all the items in the history.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> Clears the history.
- <kbd>...</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> Finds item(s) that start with ...
- <kbd>F9</kbd> Selects an item from the history by number.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> Removes all macrodefinitions.

On DOS 6.2 the storage space is always limited to 128 bytes, allowing an input
of 127 characters and room for the mandatory carriage return. It's not
possible to pre-load a template, so always set the 2nd byte of the input
buffer to zero.
On DOS Win95 the storage space can be as big as 255 bytes if you installed the
DOSKEY.COM TSR with a command like `doskey /line:255`. It's possible to
pre-load the storage space with a template. This brings the Win95 version
very close to what is feasable with input function 0Ah.

This function does <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>
checking.

When this function finishes, the cursor will be in the far left column on the
current row. If the character count is zero, it means that the user typed in
the name of a DOSKEY macro that was not yet expanded. You don't
get to see the un-expanded line! A second invocation of the function is needed
and upon returning this time, the cursor will be behind the last character of
the expanded text.
A peculiarity is that when a multi-command macro (`$T`) gets expanded, you only
get the expanded text of the 1st command. Additional invocations of the
function are needed to get the other expanded texts. Although all of this is
very useful from within a command shell like COMMAND.COM, from within a user
application it's really annoying that you can't know when this happens.

Since the inputted text is added to the command history, it is unavoidable that
the history fills up with unrelated items. Certainly not what you want to see
at the DOS prompt!

Example 3, Invoking DOSKEY.COM.

```
        ORG     256                     ;Create .COM program
        cld
        mov     ax, 4800h               ;DOSKEY.CheckInstalled
        int     2Fh                     ; -> AL
        test    al, al
        mov     si, err1
        jz      Exit_
Again:  mov     si, msg1
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     dx, buf
        mov     ax, 4810h               ;DOSKEY.BufferedInput
        int     2Fh                     ; -> AX
        test    ax, ax
        mov     si, err2
        jnz     Exit_
        cmp     [buf+1], al             ;AL=0
        je      Again                   ;Macro expansion needed
        mov     si, msg2
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     si, buf+2
        movzx   bx, byte [si-1]         ;Get character count (is GT 0)
        mov     word [si+bx+1], 10      ;Keep CR, append LF and 0
Exit_:  call    WriteStringDOS
Exit:   mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ds:si) OUT ()
WriteStringDOS:
        pusha
        jmps    .b
.a:     mov     dl, al
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
.b:     lodsb
        test    al, al
        jnz     .a
        popa
        ret
; --------------------------------------
buf:    db      128, 0, 128+2 dup (0)
msg1:   db      'Choose color ? ', 0
msg2:   db      13, 10, 'You chose ', 0
err1:   db      'N/A', 13, 10, 0
err2:   db      'Failed', 13, 10, 0
; --------------------------------------
```

## Inputting text using `int 21h AH=08h`

> Because of the 30000 byte limit that Stack Overflow imposes the text continues in the below answer...

Problem understanding the source? The assembler I used:

- considers labels that start with a dot ( **.** ) as 1st level local labels
- considers labels that start with a colon ( **:** ) as 2nd level local labels
- is Single Instruction Multiple Operands (SIMO), so `push cx si`
  translates to `push cx` `push si`.

Answer (score 4):

## Inputting text using `int 21h AH=08h`

All three input methods described until now (in the above answer!) were clearly tailor-made to suit Microsoft tools like EDLIN.EXE and COMMAND.COM.
If you are writing your own application then better results can be achieved
through producing your own input procedure. At the heart of such a procedure
will be one of the DOS single character input functions. I chose the [STDIN
Input](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2561.htm) function 08h because I want to allow
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> checking and I
intend to echo the characters myself via BIOS `Int 10h AH=09h`
[Write Character And Attribute At Cursor Position](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0099.htm). This way I can
avoid messing up any redirected output.

Programmatically there's no difference in using this *BufferedInput* procedure
or the *DOS.BufferedInput* system call. However for the user at the keyboard
inputting will be much easier since all the keys associated with the old and
difficult template editing have been dismissed and replaced by the usual
editing keys that enable you to freely move the cursor around.

- <kbd>Left</kbd> Moves cursor left.
- <kbd>Right</kbd> Moves cursor right.
- <kbd>Home</kbd> Moves cursor to the far left.
- <kbd>End</kbd> Moves cursor to the far right.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> Removes all characters to the left.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> Removes all characters to the right.
- <kbd>Delete</kbd> Removes the current character.
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> Removes the character to the left of the cursor.
- <kbd>Escape</kbd> Removes all the characters.
- <kbd>Return</kbd> Ends input.

If the 2nd byte of the input buffer holds a non-zero value then the storage space
is supposed to contain an old string (perhaps from a previous input). DOS would
have called this the template. Different from DOS is that:

- the old string is not required to be carriage return terminated.
- the old string is immediately shown on screen.

While the input is in progress, tabs are **not** expanded and the input is
confined to staying within the current row. Longer texts will scroll horizontally.
When the input is finally done, the completed text is written once **with** tab
expansion (on screen, the storage space will always hold ASCII 9) and no longer restricted to a single row.

This procedure does <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>
checking.

When this procedure finishes, the cursor will be in the far left column on the
current row.

This procedure was written with [input redirection and output redirection](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/828-standard_i_o_and_i_o_redirection.html)
in mind, and thus well suited for console applications.
One effect of input redirection is that it's useless to echo any temporary output to the screen. Either the user is not there to gaze at the screen or the temporary output will be gone in the blink of an eye.

Example 4, Improved Buffered STDIN input.

```
        ORG     256                     ;Create .COM program
        cld
        mov     si, msg1
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     dx, buf
        call    BufferedInput           ;Replaces 'mov ah, 0Ah : int 21h'
        mov     si, msg2
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     si, buf+2
        movzx   bx, byte [si-1]         ;Get character count
        mov     word [si+bx+1], 10      ;Keep CR, append LF and 0
        call    WriteStringDOS
        mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ds:si) OUT ()
WriteStringDOS:
        pusha
        jmps    .b
.a:     mov     dl, al
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
.b:     lodsb
        test    al, al
        jnz     .a
        popa
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ds:dx) OUT ()
BufferedInput:

; Entry DS:DX   Buffer of max 1+1+255 bytes
;               1st byte is size of storage space starting at 3rd byte
;               2nd byte is size of old (CR-terminated) string, 0 if none
;               Storage space can contain old (CR-terminated) string
; Exit  DS:DX   Nothing changed if header bytes were invalid
;               1st byte unchanged
;               2nd byte is size of new CR-terminated string
;               Storage space contains new CR-terminated string
; Local [bp-1]  PAGE    Display page
;       [bp-2]  STORE   Size of storage space
;       [bp-3]  ROW     Row of input box
;       [bp-4]  COL     Column of input box
;       [bp-5]  SHIFT   Number of characters shifted out on the leftside
;       [bp-6]  INBOX   Size of input box
;       [bp-7]  LIX     Number of characters in current input string
;       [bp-8]  CIX     Position of cursor in current input string
;       [bp-10] FLAGS   Bit[0] is ON for normal keyboard input

        pusha
        mov     si, dx
        lodsw                           ; -> SI points at storage space
        test    al, al                  ;AL is size of storage space
        jz      .Quit                   ;No storage space!
        cmp     ah, al                  ;AH is size of old string
        jnb     .Quit                   ;Old string too long!
        mov     bl, al

        sub     sp, 256                 ;Local edit buffer (max size)
        mov     bp, sp
        mov     ah, 0Fh                 ;BIOS.GetVideoMode
        int     10h                     ; -> AL=Mode AH=Cols BH=Page
        push    bx                      ;STORE and PAGE
        mov     bl, ah
        mov     ah, 03h                 ;BIOS.GetCursor
        int     10h                     ; -> CX=Shape DL=Col DH=Row
        push    dx                      ;COL and ROW
        sub     bl, dl                  ;Size of the widest inbox
        xor     bh, bh
        push    bx                      ;INBOX and SHIFT
        push    bx                      ;CIX and LIX (replaces 'sub sp, 2')

        call    .ESC                    ;Clear edit buffer, reset some vars
        mov     cl, [si-1]              ;Size of old string (starts at SI)
        jmps    .b
.a:     lodsb                           ;Storage space gives old string
        push    cx si
        call    .Asc                    ;Input old string
        pop     si cx
.b:     sub     cl, 1
        jnb     .a

        xor     bx, bx                  ;STDIN
        mov     ax, 4400h               ;DOS.GetDeviceInformation
        int     21h                     ; -> AX DX CF
        jc      .c                      ;Go default to keyboard
        test    dl, dl
        jns     .d                      ;Block device, not keyboard
        shr     dl, 1
.c:     adc     bx, bx                  ; -> BX=1 if Keyboard
.d:     push    bx                      ;FLAGS

.Main:  call    .Show                   ;Refresh input box on screen
        call    .Key                    ;Get key from DOS -> AX
        mov     bx, .Scans
        test    ah, ah
        jz      .f                      ;Not an extended ASCII
        mov     [cs:.Fail], ah          ;Sentinel
.e:     lea     bx, [bx+3]
        cmp     ah, [cs:bx-1]
        jne     .e
.f:     call    [cs:bx]
        jmps    .Main

.Quit:  popa                            ;Silently quiting just like DOS
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.Scans: db           .Asc
        db      4Bh, .s4B               ;<LEFT>
        db      4Dh, .s4D               ;<RIGHT>
        db      47h, .s47               ;<HOME>
        db      4Fh, .s4F               ;<END>
        db      77h, .s77               ;<CTRL-HOME>
        db      75h, .s75               ;<CTRL-END>
        db      53h, .s53               ;<DELETE>
.Fail:  db        ?, .Beep
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.Beep:  mov     ax, 0E07h               ;BIOS.TeletypeBell
        int     10h
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.Key:   call    :1
        test    ah, ah                  ;Extended ASCII requires 2 calls
        jnz     :2
:1:     mov     ah, 08h                 ;DOS.STDINInput
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
        mov     ah, 0
:2:     xchg    al, ah
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.Show:  test    word [bp-10], 1         ;FLAGS.Keyboard ?
        jz      :Ready                  ;No, input is redirected
        movzx   di, byte [bp-6]         ;INBOX
        movzx   si, byte [bp-5]         ;SHIFT
        mov     dx, [bp-4]              ;COL and ROW
        mov     cx, 1                   ;Replication count
        mov     bh, [bp-1]              ;PAGE
        mov     bl, 07h                 ;WhiteOnBlack
:Next:  mov     ah, 02h                 ;BIOS.SetCursor
        int     10h
        mov     al, [bp+si]
        mov     ah, 09h                 ;BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute
        int     10h
        inc     dl                      ;Next column
        inc     si                      ;Next character
        dec     di
        jnz     :Next                   ;Process all of the input box

        mov     dx, [bp-4]              ;COL and ROW
        add     dl, [bp-8]              ;CIX
        sub     dl, [bp-5]              ;SHIFT
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;BIOS.SetCursor
        int     10h
:Ready: ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.BS:    cmp     byte [bp-8], 0          ;CIX
        jne     :1
        ret
:1:     call    .s4B                    ;<LEFT>
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; <DELETE>
.s53:   movzx   di, byte [bp-8]         ;CIX
        movzx   cx, byte [bp-7]         ;LIX
        sub     cx, di
        je      :2                      ;Cursor behind the current input
:1:     mov     dl, [bp+di+1]           ;Move down in edit buffer
        mov     [bp+di], dl
        inc     di
        dec     cx
        jnz     :1
        dec     byte [bp-7]             ;LIX
:2:     ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.RET:   xor     si, si
        mov     bx, [bp+256+10]         ;pusha.DX -> DS:BX
        mov     al, [bp-7]              ;LIX
        inc     bx
        mov     [bx], al                ;2nd byte is size of new string
        inc     bx
        jmps    :2
:1:     mov     dl, [bp+si]
        mov     [bx+si], dl             ;Storage space receives new string
        inc     si
:2:     sub     al, 1
        jnb     :1
        mov     byte [bx+si], 13        ;Terminating CR

        push    bx                      ;(1)
        call    .ESC                    ;Wipe clean the input box
        call    .Show                   ; and reset cursor
        pop     si                      ;(1) -> DS:SI
:3:     lodsb                           ;Final unrestricted display,
        mov     dl, al                  ; expanding tabs
        mov     ah, 02h                 ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
        int     21h                     ; -> AL
        cmp     dl, 13                  ;Cursor ends in far left column
        jne     :3

        lea     sp, [bp+256]            ;Free locals and edit buffer
        popa
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.ESC:   mov     di, 256                 ;Fill edit buffer with spaces
:1:     sub     di, 2
        mov     word [bp+di], "  "
        jnz     :1
        mov     [bp-8], di              ;DI=0 -> CIX=0 LIX=0
        mov     byte [bp-5], 0          ;SHIFT=0
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
.Asc:   cmp     al, 8                   ;<BACKSPACE>
        je      .BS
        cmp     al, 13                  ;<RETURN>
        je      .RET
        cmp     al, 27                  ;<ESCAPE>
        je      .ESC
        cmp     al, 10                  ;Silently ignoring linefeed
        jne     :1                      ; in favor of input redirection
        ret
:1:     movzx   di, byte [bp-8]              ;CIX
        movzx   si, byte [bp-7]              ;LIX
        lea     dx, [si+1]
        cmp     dl, [bp-2]              ;STORE
        jb      :3
        jmp     .Beep                   ;Storage capacity reached
:2:     mov     dl, [bp+si-1]           ;Move up in edit buffer
        mov     [bp+si], dl
        dec     si
:3:     cmp     si, di
        ja      :2
        mov     [bp+si], al             ;Add newest character
        inc     byte [bp-7]             ;LIX
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; <RIGHT>
.s4D:   inc     byte [bp-8]             ;CIX
        mov     al, [bp-7]              ;LIX
        cmp     [bp-8], al              ;CIX
        jbe     .Shift
        mov     [bp-8], al              ;CIX
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; <LEFT>
.s4B:   sub     byte [bp-8], 1           ;CIX
        jnb     .Shift
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; <HOME>
.s47:   mov     byte [bp-8], 0          ;CIX
        jmps    .Shift
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; <END>
.s4F:   mov     al, [bp-7]              ;LIX
        mov     [bp-8], al              ;CIX
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
.Shift: mov     dl, [bp-5]              ;SHIFT
        mov     al, [bp-8]              ;CIX
        cmp     al, dl
        jb      :1
        add     dl, [bp-6]              ;INBOX
        sub     al, dl
        jb      :2
        inc     al
        add     al, [bp-5]              ;SHIFT
:1:     mov     [bp-5], al              ;SHIFT
:2:     ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; <CTRL-HOME>
.s77:   call    .BS
        cmp     byte [bp-8], 0          ;CIX
        ja      .s77
        ret
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; <CTRL-END>
.s75:   call    .s53                    ;<DELETE>
        mov     al, [bp-8]              ;CIX
        cmp     al, [bp-7]              ;LIX
        jb      .s75
        ret
; --------------------------------------
buf:    db      255, 16, "I'm an OldString", 13, 255-16-1+2 dup (0)
msg1:   db      'Choose color ? ', 0
msg2:   db      10, 'You chose ', 0
; --------------------------------------
```

Problem understanding the source? The assembler I used:

- considers labels that start with a dot ( **.** ) as 1st level local labels
- considers labels that start with a colon ( **:** ) as 2nd level local labels
- is Single Instruction Multiple Operands (SIMO), so `push cx si`
  translates to `push cx` `push si`.

> For a really high performing input procedure, look at [Rich Edit Form Input](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185603/rich-edit-form-input), a Code Review contribution.

Answer (score -3):

I am a beginner like yourself. I came up with this solution.

```
    org 100h

    ORG     256
    mov     dx, msg1
    mov     ah, 09h                 ;DOS.WriteString
    int     21h
    mov     dx, buf
    mov     ah, 0Ah                 ;DOS.BufferedInput
    int     21h
    mov     dx, msg2
    mov     ah, 09h                 ;DOS.WriteString
    int     21h
    mov     dx, [buf]+2
    mov     ah, 09h                 ;DOS.WriteString
    int     21h
    mov     ax, 4C00h               ;DOS.TerminateWithExitcode
    int     21h
    ; --------------------------------------
    msg1:   db      'Input : ', '$'
    buf:    db      20 dup ('$')
    msg2:   db      13, 10, 'Output : ', '$'
    ; --------------------

    ret
```

Comment: You probably missed it, but the question in this (self-answered) Q/A is all about using the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah. What you posted as an answer, doesn't deal with what was asked. It is not an answer to the question at hand. I suggest you search for a question that actually asks about conversion from integer to hexadecimal representation, and repost your solution there.

Comment: NASM doesn't assemble `mov   dx, [buf]+2`; perhaps you meant `mov   dx, buf+2` to put that address into a register, skipping the max and actual_input length bytes?  The `20 dup ('$')` is MASM style, but recent NASM also accepts that.  (Maybe not in 2017 when @Sep posted the code in the question!).  If this had been MASM, you'd need `mov dx, OFFSET msg1` and `mov dx, OFFSET buf+2` and so on.  Anyway, clearly you didn't test it, and probably didn't read Sep's answer about why having the first byte of `buf` be `'$' = 36` is wrong, because the buffer doesn't have 36 bytes of space.

Comment: Also, the whole code block is a copy/paste of the one from the question, except for one edit to one line which you haven't even highlighted with a comment.  Or said what assembler this is for.  Also, you have two redundant `org` directives, both for the same address.  (In some assemblers, the second one might skip 256 bytes or something, although not in NASM.  NASM does assemble this with that one line changed to `mov dx, buf+2`.)  Anyway, with some edits this could be a decent answer, if you use the right max-size byte for `int 21h`/AH=0Ah, and discuss the hackiness of it, and other edits.