# Taking a string as input and then display it in assembly 8086

Tags: string, assembly, emu8086

I know how to take single character input and string input. Also I know how to display a self-chosen string using DOS functions with INT 21h. But I was wondering about how to take a string input and display the same string.

When taking string input using:

```
MOV AH, 0Ah
INT 21h
```

Where does the string get stored? In case of a single character input and output, the character is stored in the AL register. So knowing the address of the stored string, I can load the address of it in the DX register and display it, right?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to read the rest of the documentation regarding the interrupt.  It clearly explains where the buffer is defined (by you).

Answer (score 1):

> Where does the string get stored?

The string is stored starting at the third byte of the input buffer for which **you** provide a pointer in `DS:DX`.

For a very detailed explanation, with examples you can study, see 
[How buffered input works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works/47379025?s=2|0.0000#47379025)

> But I was wondering about how to take a string input and display the same string.

The examples in the linked post do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

For INT 21, AH=0Ah, the caller passes in the buffer in which to store the string in DS:DX.

See Ralf Brown's interrupt list for full information about using interrupts. One of many places you can find it is http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm.