# Extracting digit at end of string assembly 8086 masm

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I have to extract digit stored in si register. here is my code

```
lea si, userInput
inc si

mov bx, [si]

mov dx, [si+bx]
add dx, 30h
mov ah, 2h 
int 21h
```

So i think code works fine if i put hard value in dx register like `mov dx, [si+2]` but if try to use `mov dx, [si+bx]` it does not work and does not give ouput as expected

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to do.  But there are a few things I notice.  For example you are doing `inc si` right after your `lea`.  So you are skipping the first byte?  Then you do `mov bx, [si]`.  That reads 2 bytes from [si] (since bx is 16bits long).  I'm not sure what `mov dx, [si+bx]` is supposed to do.  If the mov from the line above loads 1234 into bx, then this would read the byte at [si + 1234].  That can't be what you want?  Then you do `mov dx, 30h` right before calling int 21.  Do you really always intend to print 0?  Or did you mean to `add` 30h?

Comment: sorry I added `mov dx, 30h` by mistake it should have been `add dx, 30h` so bx contains the length of the address stored in si and I am using it to print specific index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your *userInput* points at the input structure required for DOS's buffered input function 0Ah, these are my recommandations to correct your code:

- The second **byte** holds the number of inputted characters. You mistakenly retrieve this as if it were a **word**.
- The input consists of characters that are **1 byte** wide. You currently retrieve it as if they were **2 bytes**.
- Since the input is already made up of **characters**, you don't need to do any conversion on it. (The attempt `mov dx, 30h`) The fact that this character could represent a (numerical) digit, a letter, a punctuation mark, or anything else, doesn't change this.

Your code then becomes:

```
lea si, userInput
inc si

mov bl, [si]     ;Number of inputted characters
mov bh, 0        ;Need to zero to be able to use the whole address-register BX next

mov dl, [si+bx]  ;Retrieve the last inputted character (right before the terminating CR)
mov ah, 02h 
int 21h          ;Display the character
```

Comment: thanks, I think I was putting everything into `bx` register directly that's why it was giving weird results

Comment: @doeydoe You can find some additional info about this DOS input mechanism in another post of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works. First chapter in the answer there.

Comment: i have one more question i am using this loop to print everything where dx is 1 `loop1:
    mov dx, [si+bx]

    cmp dx, 1
    je match

    cmp bx, 1
    je endLoop

    sub bx, 1
    jmp loop1 

match:
    mov ah, 2h 
    int 21h
    jmp loop1

endLoop:` but it is not entering `match` loop when dx is 1

Comment: @doeydoe Please notice that you need to change all of those `DX` 's into `DL`. It's always a single byte! Also I think you want to compare with the **character 1**, so write `cmp dl, '1'`

Comment: thanks now it is entering loop but it is getting into endless loop `loop1:
    mov dl, [si+bx]

    cmp dl, '1'
    je match

    cmp bx, 1
    je endLoop

    sub bx, 1
    jmp loop1 

match:
    mov ah, 2h 
    int 21h
    sub bx, 1
    jmp loop1`

Comment: @doeydoe Beware for the endless loop if a match is found! Don't jump back to *loop1*, but rather jump back to the instruction that compares `bx` to 1.

Comment: @doeydoe  In your last draft, the second `sub bx, 1` can't stay.

Comment: i had removed `sub bx, 1` i tried to using `ret` instead of `jmp` but it takes input again and again

Comment: @doeydoe You can't just choose an instruction at random! Insert an extra label between `je endLoop` and `sub bx, 1`, and then jump to that label from right after the `int 21h` instruction.