# Display buffered input to screen

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm, dosbox

I'm new in x86 assembly language and I'm reading this website [http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html#ah0a)
And I'm not sure about the effect of buffered input on DS:DX, this part:
"Entry: DS:DX -> buffer (see below)"

I know that int 21h will check the AH register and dispatch the function specified in it. For 0Ah function (buffered input), I don't understand the effects of it on other registers (DS and DX) when executed.

I looked everywhere but I always end up finding using a procedure called ReadString using the Irvine library, but I don't need that.

What I'm trying to do is to display the string inputted using the buffered input function (0Ah) to the screen using the 09h function (used to display string). Can anyone provide and explain a simple way to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works The first answer describes how to use `BUFFER INPUT (0Ah)` with a great example how to use it in assembly.