# Macros to read and print a character in assembly

Tags: assembly, macros, dos, x86-16, tasm

I'm learning macros in assembly and I'm stuck somewhere. I tried to read and print only one character as follows in macro file. (I want to learn how to use functions 01h and 02h because by now I know how to use functions 09h and 0Ah):

```
READCHAR MACRO INPUT2
MOV AH, 01H
INT 21H
ENDM

PRINTCHAR MACRO INPUT2
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H
ENDM
```

I call them as follows in .ASM file:

```
.data
EMPTYCHAR DB 1, ?, 1 DUP (‘$’)
.code
READCHAR EMPTYCHAR 
PRINTCHAR EMPTYCHAR
```

It fails and I couldn't figure out why. Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  *EMPTYCHAR* structure in your program fits the [DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works) that you say you don't want to use (this time). However it doesn't serve any purpose with the functions you intend to use today.

The *READCHAR* macro doesn't need an argument at all. The DOS.GetCharacter function 01h will return the ASCII code for the pressed key in the `AL` register.
On the other hand **the *PRINTCHAR* macro does require an argument to be of any use**. After all the DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h expects to receive an ASCII code in the `DL` register.

This is how your macros should be written:

```
READCHAR MACRO
  mov ah, 01h    ; DOS.GetCharacter
  int 21h        ; -> AL
ENDM

PRINTCHAR MACRO TheArg
  mov dl, TheArg
  mov ah, 02h    ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int 21h
ENDM
```

and how you can use them:

```
.data
Char DB 0
.code
READCHAR         ; -> AL
mov [Char], al   ; Only in case you desire to save a copy in memory, else strike this line!
PRINTCHAR al
```

Specifying the parameter for the *PRINTCHAR* macro is not limited to just the `AL` register. You could also supply an immediate number like in `PRINTCHAR 13` (to output carriage return) and `PRINTCHAR "-"` (to output a hyphen), or even a memory reference like in `PRINTCHAR [Char]`.

Note also that sometimes it could be useful to preserve some register(s) like shown below:

```
PRINTCHAR MACRO TheArg
  push dx
  mov  dl, TheArg
  mov  ah, 02h    ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h
  pop  dx
ENDM
```

Comment: thank you for your answer mate it helped me understand what I'm doing and what should be done! one extra question I have in mind tough: whenever I add a line between the read and print in asm file it fails( like this :  readchar printstring line(line DB 0DH,0AH,'$') printchar) do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: @opia If you literally write `printstring line(line DB 0DH,0AH,'$')`, it is not an allowed syntax. But assuming `line db 13,10,'$'` is placed somewhere outside of the execution path, and that you define your *printstring* macro as: `PRINTSTRING MACRO TheArg` `lea dx, TheArg` `mov ah, 09h` `int 21h` `ENDM`, invoking that macro will work if you do it like: `printstring [line]`. This is with surrounding square brackets so it is recognized as a memory reference.

Comment: yes that line was in data segment. thanks for ending my strugglings buddy, literally...i owe you

Answer (score 2):

[`INT 21H / AH = 01H` puts the character read into the `AL` register](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm), but [`INT 21H / AH = 02H` expects the character to be written in the `DL` register](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm).

So try a `MOV DL, AL` in between the two calls.

Note that as it stands your `EMPTYCHAR` buffer is not doing anything at all; these calls don't use a memory buffer, and indeed your macros don't even use their `INPUT2` parameters.  I'm not sure what you were intending it to do; if you want to put the character into memory, you'll have to store it there yourself.