# Take input in string and then write it into file in assembly language 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to write a code which take string as input and write it into a file in assembly language. In my following code i have initialize a string in DUP and then write it into assembly language. But now i want to take intput from user and then write it into a file. How can i do it.

```
;           
;Newline macro
newline macro
    mov dx , 10
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h 
    mov dx , 13
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h
endm
;   Macro to output string
stringoutput macro str1
    lea dx , str1
    mov ah , 09h
    int 21h 
endm
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
FNAME db "write.txt" , 0
string1 db 1 dup("Happy Codding!!")
string2 db "Write in File successful.$"
string6 db "*********Instruction**********$"
string3 db "For this program first you have to create a $"
string5 db "file named as write.txt in BIN folder then coninue..$"
.code
main proc
        mov ax , @data
        mov ds , ax
        newline
        stringoutput string6
        newline
        stringoutput string3
        newline
        stringoutput string5
        newline
        mov dx , offset FNAME        
        mov al , 02h                     
        mov ah , 3Dh                    
        int 21h
        mov cx , lengthof string1        
        mov bx , ax                     
        mov dx , offset string1             
        mov ah , 40h                     
        int 21h
        newline
        stringoutput string2
        newline
        mov ah , 03eh
        int 21h              
        
        mov ah , 04ch
        int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: By using one of the suitable interrupts, e.g. [int 21h / ah=0ah](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a)

Comment: You can find several ways to input a string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works), including the one @Michael suggests.