# How can I save the string I entered to use it again in emu8086?

Tags: string, assembly, input, emu8086

How can I save the string I entered to use it again
I tried changing the value of A1,A2 for example:

A1        DB  ?

and

A1        DB  '$\'

```
.DATA
P1  DB  'Enter the First Strig : $\'
P2  DB  'Enter the Second character : $\'
L   db 0ah,0dh,'$'
P3  DB  ' the " $\'   
P4  DB  ' " and " $\'   
P5  DB  ' " is: $\' 
FIRST_BASE       db 255
SECOND_BASE      db 255
A1        DB  dup('$')
A2        DB  dup('$')
.code 
.model small 
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax 

printString P1                            
lea dx, FIRST_BASE                             
mov ah,0ah  
int 21h 
MOV A1,AH            < --------- (!!!Here's the problem I can't save the string!!!)  
printString L                              
                             
                                    

printString P2                           
lea dx, SECOND_BASE                             
mov ah,0ah
MOV A2,AH     < --------- (!!!Here's the problem I can't save the string!!!)
int 21h  
printString L
```

for printing

(2)= Here he prints strange shapes and letters

```
printString P3 
printString A1             <-----------(2)
printString P4 
printString A2             <-----------(2)
printString P5                          
mov ax,ham_dist
```

I want it to look like this = the "(The string that I entered first) " and "(The string you entered second) " is:(Did not matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines like `A1 DB ?` and `A1 DB '$\'` don't reserve enough bytes to be of any use when it comes to storing a string.

> ```
> FIRST_BASE       db 255
> SECOND_BASE      db 255
> A1        DB  dup('$')
> A2        DB  dup('$')
> ...
> lea dx, FIRST_BASE                             
> mov ah,0ah  
> int 21h 
> MOV A1,AH            < --------- (!!!Here's the problem I can't save the string!!!)
> ```

This is **not** how you setup for this DOS function! Do those *A1* and *A2* lines even compile (without a numeric value in front of the `dup`)? Also a line like `MOV A1,AH` makes no sense; the `AH` register still contains the function number 0Ah, hardly anything interesting.

You can read all about the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah in [How buffered input works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works).

Since you need more than one string input, you could choose to setup 1 input buffer and copy the strings to their own private buffers, or you could setup 2 input buffers and leave the strings where they were inputted. I chose the latter:

```
FIRST_BASE       db 80, 0, 80 dup (0) 
SECOND_BASE      db 80, 0, 80 dup (0)

...

lea dx, FIRST_BASE                             
mov ah, 0Ah  
int 21h

...
```

And this is how you read the length of the inputted text:

```
mov bl, [FIRST_BASE + 1]
mov bh, 0
```

And this is how you make the inputted text $-terminated, ready for printing:

```
mov byte ptr [FIRST_BASE + 2 + bx], '$'
```

And this is how you print this:

```
lea dx, FIRST_BASE + 2
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
```