# How to skip spaces at the beginning of the string in assembly x86

Tags: string, assembly, whitespace, x86-16

What loop should I write If I want to skip all spaces at the beginning of the string and start to do something with the string when my code reaches the first symbol of the string. If I have a string like

```
a='        s o m e word'
```

the code should start when 's' is reached. It should be some kind of loop but I still don't know how to write it correctly.

My try:

```
    mov  si, offset buff+2 ;buffer

    mov ah, [si]
    
    loop_skip_space:
        cmp ah,20h ;chech if ah is space            
        jnz increase ;if yes increase si 
        jmp done ;if no end of loop
        increase:
                          
            inc si 

    loop loop_skip_space
    
    done:
```

Comment: All whitespace or just ASCII 0x20 space?  If the latter, `pcmpeqb xmm0, [rdi]` / with a vector constant / `pmovmskb` / `not` / `bsf` can find the first non-space in a vector of 16 bytes, and yeah you can do that in a loop.  For a simple scalar version, you could write it in C or Rust or other "simple" language and look at compiler output.

Comment: The traditional x86 method would put the address of the string is `esi` and do something like `myloop: lodsb` / `cmp al, ' '` / `jne myloop`, although you'd probably want to check for end-of-string too.

Comment: @harold updated my question

Comment: You can use `rep scasb` to find not space char.

Comment: @Igor Where should I put it in the code?

Comment: Can somebody write code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this 16-bit code that fetches its string offset at `buff+2`, I believe it's a safe bet to consider this string to belong to the input gotten from executing the [DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works).
The code snippets below are based on this assumption. Next observations about the OP's code remain valid anyway.

- The `mov ah, [si]` must be part of the loop. You need to verify different characters from the string, so loading following bytes is necessary.
- Your code should exit the loop upon finding a **non-space** character. Currently you exit upon the first space.
- The `loop` instruction requires setting up the `CX` register with the length of the string. You omitted that.

```
  mov  si, offset buff+2
  mov  cl, [si-1]
  mov  ch, 0
  jcxz done               ; String could start off empty
loop_skip_space:
  cmp  byte ptr [si], ' '
  jne  done
  inc  si                 ; Skip the current space
  loop loop_skip_space
done:
```

Here `SI` points at the first non-space character in the string with `CX` characters remaining. `CX` could be zero!

---

You can write better code if you stop using the `loop` instruction, because it's an instruction that is said to be slow. See [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).

1. Avoiding `loop` and no longer requiring the use of `CX`

```
  mov  si, offset buff+2
  mov  cl, [si-1]
  test cl, cl
  jz   done               ; String could start off empty
loop_skip_space:
  cmp  byte ptr [si], ' '
  jne  done
  inc  si                 ; Skip the current space
  dec  cl
  jnz  loop_skip_space
done:
```

2. Avoiding `loop` and using the delimiter 13 (carriage return)

```
  mov  si, offset buff+1
loop_skip_space:
  inc  si
  cmp  byte ptr [si], ' '
  je   loop_skip_space
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the example

```
    STRLEN    EQU  9
    STRING    DB   'Assembler'

              CLD                    ;clear direction flag
              MOV  AL,' '            ;symbol to find.
              MOV  ECX,STRLEN         ;length of string
              LEA  EDI,STRING         ;string pointer.
              REPE SCASB            ;search itself
              JNZ  K20               ;jump if not found
              DEC  EDI                ;
; EDI points to your first not space char
    K20:      RET
```

Comment: The code for skipping the leading whitespace is wrong. You want to **repeat** the instruction **while** the character is **equal** to a space. Needs `REPE SCASB`

Comment: For an all-spaces string, you need to use `JZ K20`. Only if a non-space was encountered, do you need to back up 1 character.