# How to display the summation of two negative number in HEX while the input is decimal in x8086 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, hex, display, emu8086, negative-number

; Hello, I'm new to assembly language x8086, the problem is how can I add two negative numbers (decimal) and display them in HEX. I'm stuck at the point the code does not detect the negative numbers and I don't know how to display it in HEX. can someone help me? here my code

```
TITLE PROB12
PAGE 60,132
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64H
.DATA
NUM1 DB 8,?,8 DUP (?)
NUM2 DB 8,?,8 DUP (?)
PROMPT1 DB CR,LF,'Enter the first number','$'
PROMPT2 DB CR,LF,'Enter the second number','$'
PROMPT3 DB CR,LF,'The total sum is '
SUM DB 7 DUP (?),'$'
CR EQU 0DH
LF EQU 0AH
.CODE
MAIN: MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
CALL CLEAR ;clear screen
MOV AH,09
MOV DX,OFFSET PROMPT1
INT 21H ;display first prompt
MOV AH,0AH
MOV DX,OFFSET NUM1
INT 21H ;get first number
MOV AH,09
MOV DX,OFFSET PROMPT2
INT 21H ;display second prompt
MOV AH,0AH
MOV DX,OFFSET NUM2
INT 21H ;get second number
MOV SI,OFFSET NUM1 + 8 ;point to LSD of number 1
MOV DI,OFFSET NUM2 + 8 ;point to LSD of number 2
MOV BX,OFFSET SUM + 6 ;point to LSD of sum
MOV CX,7 ;add 7 bytes
CLC ;clear carry
ADD_LP: MOV AL,[SI] ;get byte from number 1
ADC AL,[DI] ;add byte from number 2
PUSHF ;save any carry
AAA ;ASCII adjust
OR AL,30H ;make it ASCII
POPF ;restore flags
MOV [BX],AL ;store sum (in BCD)
DEC SI ;decrement pointers
DEC DI ;to point to next byte
DEC BX
LOOP ADD_LP ;loop through 7 bytes
MOV AH,09
MOV DX,OFFSET PROMPT3
INT 21H ;display result
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H ;go back to DOS
;--------------------------------------------------
CLEAR PROC
MOV AH,06 ;clear screen function
MOV AL,00 ;page 0
MOV BH,07 ;normal attribute
MOV CX,0 ;entire screen
MOV DX,184FH
INT 10H
RET
CLEAR ENDP
END MAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm stuck at the point the code does not detect the negative numbers and I don't know how to display it in HEX

It makes no sense asking about the above if the code that you have written has more fundamental issues.

Your code uses [the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works), and hopes to find the least significant digit of the inputted numerical characters at offset 8 of the input structure. This approach can only work if the user at the keyboard **always provides precisely 7 digits**. That's not very user-friendly.

The loop that later adds two such numbers is not propagating the carry like it should! Currently you are preserving the carry from the `adc` operation, but that's pointless since it will always be clear. **You need to propagate throughout the loop the carry that you obtain from the `aaa` instruction**.

```
  MOV  CX,7    ;add 7 bytes
  CLC
ADD_LP:
  MOV  AL,[SI] ;get byte from number 1
  ADC  AL,[DI] ;add byte from number 2
  AAA          ;ASCII adjust

  PUSHF        ;save any carry
  OR   AL,30h  ;make it ASCII
  POPF         ;restore flags

  MOV  [BX],AL ;store sum (in BCD)
  DEC  SI      ;decrement pointers
  DEC  DI      ;to point to next byte
  DEC  BX
  LOOP ADD_LP  ;loop through 7 bytes
```

---

If you were going to detect a negative number then you would have to inspect the very first inputted characters `cmp byte ptr [NUM1 + 2], '-'` and `cmp byte ptr [NUM2 + 2], '-'`. If both are indeed present then the current addition is fine as long as you iterate over the remaining **6** digits (7-1) and that you write a "-" character at *SUM*.