# assembly encryption decryption program

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86-16, dos, emu8086

hello if anyone can help me with this code that im facing a problem with i dont know where exactly is the error but its only working with the first few steps then when it coms to letting the user input a message its causing an error

```
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
    ; add your data here!
    pkey db "press any key...$" 
    prompt1 db "if u want to encrypt,type E,if u want to decrypt,type D:",0Ah,0Dh,"$"
    prompt2 db "enter the encryption key(a single digit from 1 to 9):",0Ah,0Dh,"$"
    prompt3 db "input a message of no more than 20 characters ,when done press <ENTER>:",0Ah,0Dh,"$"
    message db 20 dup(?)
    result db 20 dup(?)
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
                               
                             
    ; add your code here  
    ; prompt the user for input
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset prompt1
    int 21h        
    ; read the user's input and store it in x3100
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov [3100H], al  
    ; prompt the user for the encryption key
   mov ah, 09h
   mov dx, offset prompt2
   int 21h  
   ; read the encryption key and store it in x3101
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov [3101H], al

; prompt the user for the message
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset prompt3
int 21h

; read the message and store it in x3102
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, offset message
int 21h

; encrypt/decrypt the message based on the user's input
mov al, [3100H]
cmp al, 'E'
je encrypt
cmp al, 'D'
je decrypt
; encrypt the message
encrypt:
    mov si, offset message
    mov di, offset result
    mov bx, [3101H] ; encryption key
    mov cx, 20 ; number of characters to process

encrypt_loop:
    ; toggle the low-order bit of the ASCII code
    mov al, [si]
    xor al, 1
    add al, [bx] ; add the encryption key
    mov [di], al
    inc si
    inc di
    loop encrypt_loop

; output the encrypted message
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset result
int 21h
; decrypt the message
decrypt:
    mov si, offset message
    mov di, offset result
    mov bx, [3101H] ; encryption key
    mov cx, 20 ; number of characters to process

decrypt_loop:
    ; subtract the encryption key from the ASCII code
    mov al, [si]
    sub al,[ bx]
    ; toggle the low-order bit of the result
    xor al, 1
    mov [di], al
    inc si
    inc di
    loop decrypt_loop

; output the decrypted message
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset result
int 21h

                      
                      
            
    lea dx, pkey
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx
    
    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    
    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

its telling me to correct example of int21/9h

```
mov dx,offset message 
mov ah,9
```

i dont even know where the error is

Comment: What error?  A [mcve] should quote it exactly.  Also, emu8086 has a debugger built-in, so it should be showing you what instruction triggered the error, or you can single-step.  (If you're not actually using emu8086, use a debugger for whatever environment you are using.  That's nearly essential to avoid wasting time while debugging.)

Answer (score 0):

> when it coms to letting the user input a message its causing an error

You are using the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah for inputting the string to be encoded/decoded. The trouble you're facing comes from not having supplied the correct input structure to this DOS function.
You need to change `message db 20 dup(?)` into `message db 21, 0, 21 dup(0)`. But don't take it from me just like that! Read [How buffered input works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works) for a thorough explanation.

And since you apparently want the user to input 20 characters exactly, I would have preferred the use of a simple loop over the use of the buffered input function:

```
  mov  ah, 09h
  mov  dx, offset prompt3
  int  21h
  mov  di, offset message
  mov  cx, 20
NextChar:
  mov  ah, 01h    ; DOS.GetCharacter
  int  21h        ; -> AL
  mov  [di], al
  inc  di
  loop NextChar
```

### Your program exhibits more errors

> ```
> ; read the user's input and store it in x3100
> ; read the encryption key and store it in x3101
> ; read the message and store it in x3102
> ```

Storing at fixed addresses may be something you do in architectures like LC3, but it's definitely not what you should do on x86.
Just like your current *data* program segment has storage for messages and buffers, should you add storage for these additional items.

```
EncryptionMethod db 0
EncryptionKey    db 0
```

> ```
> cmp al, 'E'
> je encrypt
> cmp al, 'D'
> je decrypt
> ; encrypt the message
> encrypt:
> ```

If the user selects anything other than 'E' or 'D', your program encrypts anyway! A decent input strategy would be to accept the lowercase commands 'e' and 'd' too, and in case of non-complying that you have the user redo from start.

> ```
> ; output the encrypted message
> mov ah, 09h
> mov dx, offset result
> int 21h
> ; decrypt the message
> decrypt:
> ```

Once you have encrypted (and displayed) a string, you immediately start decrypting it additionally. This could be intentional, but it turns selecting an encryption method ('E' or 'D') into (kind of) a silly/redundant operation.

> ```
> mov bx, [3101H] ; encryption key
> add al, [bx] ; add the encryption key
> ```

Although this is MASM style, it is confusing to see these square brackets when the number that you're loading is just an address. Simply write it as `mov bx, 3101h`. And much better if you write is as `mov bx, offset EncryptionKey`.
About the encryption key: you have asked the user for "a single digit from 1 to 9", but in absence of any conversion, the value that you have stored in memory is still the ASCII code for one of the characters "1" to "9". To obtain a value between 1 and 9, you need to subtract 48.

> its telling me to correct example of int21/9h
> i dont even know where the error is

The DOS.PrintString function 09h expects in DS:DX the far pointer to a **$**-terminated string. The 20-byte string that you have in your *result* buffer does not have that **$** terminator. Write it as `result db 20 dup(0), '$'`.