# TASM strcmp analog in ASMx86

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I need to write an analogue of the strsmp function from the C programming language in assembly language. My program seems to detect string equality correctly, but if they are not equal, then in various tests I've come up with, it always returns that the first string is greater than the second. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
assume cs: code, ds: data

data segment
    first db 255, 254 dup (0)
    second db 255, 254 dup (0)
    bigger_s db "  first string is bigger than second$"
    smaller_s db "  second string is bigger than first$"
    equal_s db "  they are equal$"
data ends

code segment

input proc
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  
  mov dx, [bp+4]
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 0Ah
  int 21h
  
  mov dx, [bp+4]
  inc dx
  mov si, dx
  mov cx, [si]
  xor ch, ch
  add si, cx
  mov byte ptr [si+1], '$'
  inc dx
  
  pop bp
  ret
input endp

print proc
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  
  mov dx, [bp+4]
  add dx, 2 
  xor ax, ax
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h
  
  pop bp
  ret
print endp

endl proc
  mov ah, 02h
  mov dl, 0Ah
  int 21h
  ret
endl endp

strcmp proc
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  
  mov si, [bp+4]
  mov di, [bp+6]
  
compare_loop:
  mov al, [si]
  mov bl, [di]
  cmp al, bl
  je continue
  sub al, bl
  pop bp
  ret
  
continue:
  inc si
  inc di
  cmp al, 0
  jne compare_loop
  
  xor ax, ax    
  pop bp
  ret
strcmp endp


main:
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax

  push offset first
  call input
  call endl
  
  push offset second
  call input
  call endl
  
  push offset first + 2
  push offset second + 2
  call strcmp
  
  cmp ax, 0
  je equal_strings
  jg first_is_greater
  jl second_is_greater

equal_strings:
  push offset equal_s
  call print
  jmp exit_program

first_is_greater:
  push offset bigger_s
  call print
  jmp exit_program

second_is_greater:
  push offset smaller_s
  call print

exit_program:
  call endl
  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h
  code ends
  end main
```

I tried to test the code on lines such as a and b, but when given such input the program showed me that the first line is larger, although this is incorrect.

Comment: For starters, `cmp ax, 0` should use `al` since your `strcmp` only sets `al` so no telling what's in `ah`.

Comment: @Jester, I've changed `cmp ax, 0` to `cmp al, 0` but the program still works incorrectly, if I give a and b as input, then it outputs that the first line is greater

Comment: When using `push` you generally use reverse order for the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sub al, bl
> pop bp
> ret
> ```

> the program still works incorrectly, if I give a and b as input, then it outputs that the first line is greater

What *strcmp* returns in AL is the difference between a character from the 2nd string (in casu "b") and a character from the 1st string (in casu "a").
This means that the final interpretation

> ```
> cmp ax, 0
> je equal_strings
> jg first_is_greater
> jl second_is_greater
>
> equal_strings:
> ```

needs to become

```
  cmp  AL, 0                 ; In casu AL == "b" - "a" == 1
  JL   first_is_greater
  JG   second_is_greater
equal_strings:
```

---

> ```
> cmp al, 0
> jne compare_loop
> ```

An additional problem in *strcmp*: testing for the end of the string should use the $ character as that is the terminator that your *input* procedure substituted.

```
  cmp  al, "$"
  jne  compare_loop
```

---

> ```
> data segment
>     first db 255, 254 dup (0)
>     second db 255, 254 dup (0)
> ```

So you can improve how you use the buffered input function 0Ah, read [How buffered input works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works).