# C's strstr() analogue in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, search, x86, tasm

I am trying to make a `strstr` analogue in asm. But I am struggling. For some reason the code does not output anything. What I am trying to do is: I pass the arguments to the *strstr* proc on the stack, then in *strstr*'s *inner_loop* I take the pointer to the symbol of the first string from which I'd like to search, after that I call the *search* proc, where I iterate on both strings and compare their characters.

P.S about input strings - its first byte is its maximum length; second byte after input will contain the actual length (number of entered characters). That is why I write `[bp+6]` and `[bp+8]`.

```
assume cs:code, ds:data

data segment
    newline db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
    string1 db 100, 99 dup (0)
    string2 db 100, 99 dup (0)
    not_found_message db 'Not found', '$'
data ends

code segment
strstr proc
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov di, [bp+4]
    add di, 2
    mov si, [bp+6]
    add si, 2

    inner_loop:
        mov al, [di]
        cmp al, '$'
        jne go_search
        je failed1

    go_search:
        push di
        push si
        call search

        pop ax

        cmp ax, 1
        je success1

        inc di
        jmp inner_loop

    success1:
        mov ax, di
        pop bp
        pop bx
        pop dx
        push ax
        push bx
        ret

    failed1:
        mov ax, -1
        pop bp
        pop bx
        pop dx
        push ax
        push bx
        ret
strstr endp

search proc
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov di, [bp+10]
    mov si, [bp+12]

    custom_loop:
        mov al, [di]
        mov bl, [si]

        cmp bl, '$'
        je success2

        cmp al, '$'
        je failed2

        cmp al, bl
        je match

        jmp failed2

    match:
        inc di
        inc si
        jmp custom_loop

    success2:
        mov ax, 1
        pop bp
        pop bx
        pop dx
        push ax
        push bx
        ret

    failed2:
        pop bp
        pop bx
        pop dx
        push ax
        push bx
        ret
search endp

start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset string1
    xor ax, ax
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h
    push dx

    mov dx, offset newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset string2
    xor ax, ax
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h
    push dx

    mov dx, offset newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    call strstr

    pop ax

    cmp ax, -1
    je not_found

    print_result:
        mov cx, 10
        test ax, ax
        jz check_done

    check_done:
        xor dx, dx
        div cx
        push dx
        test ax, ax
        jnz check_done

    print_number:
        pop dx
        add dl, '0'
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

not_found:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset not_found_message
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

I assume that the error lies in working with the stack.

Comment: `bp+6` and `bp+8` are already wrong. You need to offset `si` and `di`. Also you are searching for `$` but your strings are not terminted by `$`. Instead you have their length. There may be more errors. Use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester for input I write strings like that - 123$. And is bp+2 and bp+4 correct?

Comment: Yeah if you provide input like that it could work. But why not use the lengths if you got them? No, `[bp+4]` and `[bp+6]` are the correct addresses for the arguments. At `[bp]` you have the pushed `bp`, at `[bp+2]` you have the return address. Arguments follow.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that the error lies in working with the stack.

Indeed, most errors in the program relate to how you deal with the stack.

- Both the *strstr* and the *search* procedures are invoked with 2 arguments on the stack, but these procs erroneously leave behind one of their arguments. This occurs on four separate occasions. As an example consider:

  > ```
  > success1:
  >    mov ax, di    <- No need to transfer beforehand
  >    pop bp        <- Restore BP
  >    pop bx        <- Temporary removal of return address
  >    pop dx        <- Removal of one of the arguments
  >    push ax       <- Pushing the exit code
  >    push bx       <- Restoring the return address
  >    ret           <- The return address gets used
  > ```

  A correct sequence is:

  ```
  success1:
      mov  [bp + 6], di  ; Overwrite one of the arguments with the exit code
      pop  bp            ; Restore BP
      ret  2             ; Return and let the CPU remove the other argument for you
  ```
- In the *search* proc, you don't even use the arguments proper!

  > ```
  > mov di, [bp+10]  <- Return address of 'strstr' ???
  > mov si, [bp+12]  <- One of the arguments of 'strstr' ???
  > ```

  The correct offsets are:

  ```
  mov  di, [bp + 4]    ; The second pushed argument
  mov  si, [bp + 6]    ; The first pushed argument
  ```

  And to make more sense, better push the arguments in the same order for both the procs:

  ```
  push si              ; Where to search
  push di              ; What to search
  call search
  ```
- Because the *search* proc uses the SI and DI registers for its own purposes, upon returning to the *strstr* proc you will no longer be able to continu the *inner_loop* correctly! Preserving these registers is in order:

  ```
  search proc
    push bp             ; Preserve BP
    mov  bp, sp
    push si             ; Preserve SI
    push di             ; Preserve DI
    mov  si, [bp + 6]   ; Where to search
    mov  di, [bp + 4]   ; What to search
  custom_loop:

      ...

  success2:
    mov  ax, 1
  failed2:
    mov  [bp + 6], ax  ; Overwrite with the exit code
    pop  di            ; Restore DI
    pop  si            ; Restore SI
    pop  bp            ; Restore BP
    ret  2
  search endp
  ```

---

Please note that the *print_number* code forgets to iterate over the stacked remainders! Your result is a 16-bit offset address, therefore you can expect a number to have at most 5 decimal digits. [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) explains in detail how you can convert and display numbers.

Working with the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah could be improved too. Read all about it in [How buffered input works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works).