# reading lines in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to create a program in Assembly that can count characters in one line and save the length of the shortest into a variable.
But I don't really understand what to do and can't find help anywhere.

I have this, but it’s far from what I want it to do.

```
cpu 8086
segment code
start   mov bx,data
mov ds,bx
mov bx,stack
mov ss,bx
mov sp,dno

radek   mov ah,0x0a
mov dx,nacteno
    int 21h
mov al,[nacteno+1]
cmp al,0
jne size
jz konec

size    mov bl,[rslt34]
cmp al,bl
jle radek
mov [rslt34],al
jmp radek
konec   hlt

segment data
nacteno db 255, ?
resb 255
rslt34  db 0

segment stack
resb 16
dno:    db ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that can **count** characters in one line

Because you're using the [DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379024/how-buffered-input-works) there's not much counting needed since you get it for free in the second byte of the structure. So be it.
Surprisingly perhaps, your attempt is rather good. But because of the way you initialize *rslt34* (`rslt34  db 0`), the `cmp al,bl` `jle radek` will not close in on the shortest string but on the longest string.

You should setup *rslt34* to 255 and use next code:

```
  cmp  al, 0          ; Exit on empty string
  je   konec
size:
  cmp  al, [rslt34]
  jnb  radek          ; Ignore if not below what we already have
  mov  [rslt34], al   ; Update with a length that is smaller than before
  jmp  radek
konec:
```

The length byte that DOS gives you must be treated as an **unsigned** number. Therefore don't use signed conditional jumps like `jle` and friends. Use the unsigned conditional jumps like `jb` (JumpIfBelow), `jnb` (JumpIfNotBelow), and others.

---

> ```
> segment stack
> resb 16
> ```

Realistically, the BIOS/DOS stack should be at least 256 bytes, preferably 512 bytes.

---

> ```
> konec   hlt
> ```

The usual way to exit from a DOS program uses next instructions:

```
mov  ax, 4C00h    ; DOS.TerminateProgram
int  21h
```

Comment: Thank you, now it does what it's supposed to